# How do I rename a report

Tags: custom-reports

I have copied a report which shows the title as "Copy plus the report name"

How do I change the name of this copy?

Answer (score 2):

When viewing the report results click on the Title and Format tab at the top. Change the name. Then from the actions dropdown below the Refresh Results button choose Save.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.